# dropdown list howto have default selected with angular

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html

I've created a dropdown list via:

```
 <li>
    <a href="#" 
    ng-click="check(default)">defaul_label</a>
</li>
```

and simply styling so it drops down well, so all my items loop through fine.

Without using a select field, how can I specify what link would be 'selected' to show as the default selected item?

Comment: you could ng-show="isSelected", something like that

Comment: Just to add to that - it would depend on how you have your custom drop down set up. Like do you have the css hiding everything thats not the selected value, or do you have a custom data attribute to define the value or something.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `ng-class` directive to set an 'active' class on the selected item. In your `ng-click`, you would set the active index using the `$index` value from the `ng-repeat` directive.

HTML

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{active:activeIndex === $index}">
  <a href="" ng-click="setActiveIndex($index)">{{item}}</a>
</li>
```

JS

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.activeIndex = 0;
  $scope.items = [
    "One",
    "Two",
    "Three",
    "Four"
  ];

  $scope.setActiveIndex = function(idx) {
    $scope.activeIndex = idx;
  };
});
```

[Here is a codepen](http://codepen.io/caroach1080/pen/QbOWZJ)

Comment: I also need to pass my default function called check() how would I implement these with that? as I need to call only one ng-click=check()

Comment: You can consolidate this into your $.scope.setActiveIndex() function, underneath Coreys existing functionality just call the check() inside there just as you would inside of the ng-click="check()"